# Pytorch gradient calulation of one Tensor

Tags: pytorch

I'm a beginner in pytorch and I'm probably stuck on a relatively trivial problem, but it's not clearing up for me at the moment.

When calculating the gradient of a tensor I get a constant gradient of 1.
Shouldn't the gradient of a constant however result in 0?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(50., requires_grad=True)

y = x

y.backward()

print(x.grad)
#Ouput: tensor(1.)
```

So why is the ouput 1 and not 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not computing the gradient of a constant, but that of the variable `x` which has a constant value 50. The derivative of `x` with respect to `x` is 1.